# Правильное удаление виджетов

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Допустим, я добавляю pushbutton в режиме дизайна. Нажимаю "перейти к слоту", тем самым создавая метод onPushBotton_clicked. В дальнейшем, я удаляю эту кнопку вместе с кодом. В результате, позже, при компиляции, получаю ошибку `undefined reference to MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()`.
Ничего в коде ценного нет, поэтому начал заново, но все-таки как правильно удалять виджеты, чтобы в дальнейшем не возникало таких ошибок? И можно ли что-то сделать, если ошибка уже есть?
Пробовал "очистить все" с пересборкой - не помогло

Comment: удалил строчку `void on_pushButton_clicked();` в `mainwindow.h` помогло, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не есть хорошо...

Comment: в .cpp еще удалите тело метода (если оно осталось)

Comment: @gil9red да, удалил. Этого достаточно? Меня не покидает ощущение, что где-то там от этой кнопки что-то осталось.

Comment: Да, нормально. В ответе расскажу подробнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда дизайнер создал метод с именем `on_pushButton_clicked`, он "сказал" что есть виджет с objectName=pushButton и этот метод нужно привязать к сигналу виджета `clicked`.

Такие методы это шаблоны вида: `on_<objectName>_<signal>`.

Но наличие метода с таким название не достаточно, нужно еще вызвать метод `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`. Когда вы создавали `ui` файл, Qt Creator на основе его создавал `cpp` файл, в котором кодом создавались виджеты на форме в методе `setupUi` и в этом методе как раз вызывается `connectSlotsByName`, чтобы привязать методы к сигналам.

Вот такая динамическая привязка сигналов виджетов к методам.

---

Поэтому, удаление метода `on_pushButton_clicked` из `h`/`cpp` файлов достаточно. Но я бы еще посмотрел в дизайнере формы что этот сигнал удален.

Comment: Вроде бы удален. Большое спасибо за ответ